# Multiple search on column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, modern-experience, list-form

I have one list - **List 1** with 3 columns (*ID, Name, Surname*), and another one - **List 2** with lookup column connected to *ID*, but I need the ***search to be able to work with name and surname columns too***.

For example if my ID is 12345 and I started entering 12 in lookup column it will suggested me 12345, but what I need is to write Simona and suggest me all ID's from people with name Simona.
Is this possible thing to do, or any workaround how can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using SharePoint out of the box capabilities of lookup columns.

If you are using modern experience, you have to customize the list forms using Power Apps.

**Documentation**: [Customize a SharePoint list or library form by using Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)